# TypeScript excess field checking and type inference error

Tags: typescript, type-inference

It seems I've run into a weird edge case of the TS compiler, when it comes to type inference. The code below (with the commented lines as is), should (I believe) produce a compile error, but it actually doesn't.

```
interface IReturned {
    theField?: string;
}
interface IFactory {
    (): IReturned;
}
var factory : IFactory = function () /* : IReturned */{
    return {
        BROKEN: 'ERROR'
    }
};
var instance = factory();
// instance.BROKEN;
```

What ideally should happen is that the return type of the factory function is inferred as IReturned, meaning that it's a compile error to return an object literal with excess fields from it, therefore setting the "BROKEN" property should not be valid.

If the function is explicitly annotated with IReturned as its returned type, this is indeed what happens. The type of the "instance" variable is also inferred correctly, and trying to access the "BROKEN" field on the line below is also an error.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to get this working without having to add redundant type definitions everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is accepted because it is compatible.

Suppose you define an interface `IRet2` that extends `IReturned` and adds a field `BROKEN`. Because the interface `IRet2` extends `IReturned`, it is valid to return an object of type `IRet2` where you have to return an `IReturned`:

```
interface IReturned {
    theField?: string;
}
interface IRet2 extends IReturned {
    BROKEN: string;
}
interface IFactory {
    (): IReturned;
}
var factory : IFactory = function (): IRet2 {
    return {
        BROKEN: 'ERROR'
    }
};
var instance = factory();
```

Your code follows the same principle, but with an inferred type that implicitly extends `IReturned`.